# How can I create & edit database of Sql Azure using SQL Server 2008 - R2 

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

I have sql azure database and to create and edit database using portal is very boring task due to it' user interface, when i will connect it with my local sql server R2 then i can not able to edit , create table from there.

Is there any way to make it possible , Please give me some solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all i found one 3rd party client to manage SQL Azure and that is RazorSQL- Awesome tool! I have write down about it in my blog, [see here](http://www.arunrana.net/2011/11/razorsql-very-useful-client-to-manage.html)

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the two options available are the web user interface (which will be improved over time) and SQL Server Mgmt Studio (using queries; no user interface) for which SQL Azure support will also improve over time.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat is a commercial application that offers access.

http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlserver

Personally I vastly prefer it to the Microsoft web interface